# Javaで削除効率の良い優先度付きキューとして使えるクラスはありますか？

Tags: java

Java SEコアAPIに次の条件を満たすコンテナクラスは用意されているでしょうか。

(1)重複要素を許す
(2)最大値/最小値の取得がO(1)
(3)任意の要素の削除がO(log(n))

STLでは[`multiset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/)がこれらの性質を満たしています。一方Javaでこのようなクラスを探してみたところ、近いものとして[`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)と[`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)が挙がりました。 しかし前者は削除に線形時間かかり、後者は重複要素を許さないため条件に合いませんでした。

`TreeSet`とタプルを使えば同じことを実現できると思いますが、先に挙げた性質を満たすクラスがあるかどうかを知りたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TreeMapを使えばどうですか？やりたいことに一番近いんじゃないかなと。

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();

// 要素の追加
Integer n = treeMap.get(i);
if (n == null) {
  n = 0;
}
treeMap.put(i, n + 1);

// 最大値
treeMap.lastKey();

// 最小値
treeMap.firstKey();

// 削除
Integer n = treeMap.get(i);
if (n != null) {
  treeMap.put(i, n - 1);
}

// 存在確認
Integer n = treeMap.get(i);
boolean hasValue = (n != null && n > 0);
```

オーダーの計算はあまり得意じゃないので雰囲気ですが、ソースを見る感じと木構造というのを考えると要素の操作はO(log(n))になりそうです。
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java

Comment: 他には良さそうなものは見当たらなかったので、ArrayListあたりを継承してSortedListみたいなものを作ると良いんじゃないでしょうか……

Comment: [ドキュメント](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)には削除がlog(n)とありました。またソースを見ましたが、最小値の取得にはツリーを辿っているので、仰る通りこれもlog(n)のようですね。